# Database object with different data

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-6

I'm making a web page in ASP.NET MVC which compares prices from different shops.

I have a one-to-many with products and the shops, where the `SHOP` has one `PRODUCT` and a `PRODUCT` has many `SHOP`s, the problem is that the product is the same but the price is different.

Example:

```
3 shops sells one fork.
Shop 1: $10
Shop 2: $20
Shop 3: $30
```

Is the best way to make a new product for each shop or can I some how change the price?

Comment: @Sachu don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally what you want is a many-to-many relationship between your `Shop` and `Product` entities:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int ShopId {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ShopProduct> ShopProducts {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ShopProduct> ShopProducts {get; set;}
}

public class ShopProduct
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public int ShopId {get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
    public virtual Shop Shop {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

By the above example, each `Shop` can have many `Product`s and each `Product` can exist in many `Shop`s. At the junction of each `Shop`-`Product` combination, you specify the price. Let me show an example:

```
ID | Shop Name
--------------
1    Shop 1
2    Shop 2
3    Shop 3

ID | Product Name
-----------------
1    Fork
```

So now we can do this (your example from above):

```
ProductId | ShopId | Price
----------------------------------------------------
1           1        10.00  <- fork for Shop 1 @ $10
1           2        20.00  <- fork for Shop 2 @ $20
1           3        30.00  <- fork for Shop 3 @ $30
```

You can now add as many shops and products as you want, and link them in the many-to-many table. A table like this is called a **junction table** in database parlance.

Answer (score 1):

I would create 3 tables for that

```
Table Shop
 - ShopId (PK)
 - Name
 - ...

Table Product
 - ProductId (PK)
 - Name
 - ...

Table Price
 - ShopId (FK)
 - ProductId (FK)
 - Price
 - Date (optional if you want price history)
```

If you want price history then fields `ShopId, ProductId, Date` have to form unique constraint

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have separate table for field such as `Price` and having two `foreign keys` in that new table i.e one of `product` and other of `shop`.